# How to correctly scale image to fit into maxdim-by-maxdim square area?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to create a JS expression to set the scale for an image after being a given original height and width so that it can exactly fit inside a maxdim-by-maxdim square area (touching at least two edges). How would I complete my function? I think I am missing the scaling equation.

```html
function scaleImage(width, height, maxdim) {
  var scale = ?;
  return [scale * width, scale * height];
}
```

Comment: So, did you get the job at Collage?

Answer (score 2):

Try using [Math.max()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/abs).

Here is the full snippet:

```
function scaleImage(width, height, maxdim) {
  var scale = maxdim / Math.max(width, height);
  return [scale * width, scale * height];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━

## ⚖ Scales ⚖

## ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━

### ⚖ Demo 1

## ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━

A simple function that set and changes a given element's CSS property: **[`transform:scale()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/scale)**.

---

#### scaleImage(selector, X, Y)

**Parameters:**

- **selector:** A CSS string of the element target.
- **X:** The horizontal scale value (Ratio 1:1 ex. 2 is twice the distance)
- **Y:** The vertical countervalue of X.

---

```js
function scaleImage(selector, X, Y) {
  var node = document.querySelector(selector);
  node.style.transform = `scale(${X}, ${Y})`;
}


scaleImage('.scale', 2, 2);
```

```css
.scale {
  display: block;
  margin: 100px auto 0;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<img src='https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2013/07/12/13/44/scales-147219_960_720.png' class='scale'>
```

---

---

## ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━

### ⚖ Demo 2

## ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━

Features 3 different functions that set and change rulesets of specific CSS properties that when applied (along with possible requirements, see links,) will adjust the width and height of an image to the edge of its parent element while maintaining its aspect ratio (no distortion).

---

#### Fig 1.

#### styler(selector, propertyName, propertyValue)

[**setProperty()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleDeclaration/setProperty)

Set and change any applicable CSS property of a given element. In **Demo 2, Fig 1**, there were 2 CSS properties to change so for the matter of convenience, both calls to `styler()` were wrapped in an empty function: `wrap()`. The 2 CSS properties are: **[`height:auto` and `width:100%`](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/201112/the_difference_between_widthauto_and_width100/)**

---

#### Fig 2.

#### classSizer(selector, classNAME)

[**classList.toggle()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList)

Toggles (set or remove) any *className* on any given element. The *className* can be an existing one or assigned on the fly. You should have the *className* declared on a stylesheet (`<link href="....css">`) or style tag (`<style>`...`</style>`) beforehand. In **Demo 2, fig 2.**, the second parameter: `.oFit` is a declared *className* with the properties of: **[`object-fit: contain`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit)** and **[`min-width: {width of parent}`](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/201112/the_difference_between_widthauto_and_width100/)**.

---

#### Fig 3.

#### scaleBkg(selector, url)

[**cssText**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleDeclaration/cssText)

Set and change any given element's CSS properties: **[`background-image:url({url of image})`, `background-repeat:no-repeat`, and `background-size:contain`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Backgrounds_and_Borders/Scaling_background_images)**. The second parameter: **url** is the url to an image.

---

## ━━━━━━━━━━━━ Demo 2 ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━

```js
/* Just a function to call styler() function to set:
|| CSS Property: width:100%; height:auto
*/
function wrap(e) {
  styler('#fig1 img', 'width', '100%');
  styler('#fig1 img', 'height', 'auto');
}

/* Method: setProperty() 
|| CSS Property: Any applicable
*/
function styler(selector, propertyName, propertyValue) {
  var node = document.querySelector(selector);
  node.style.setProperty(propertyName, propertyValue);
}

//~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

/* Method/Prop: classList
|| API Property: .toggle
|| CSS Property: object-fit: contain; min-width: {width of parent}
*/
function classSizer(selector, classNAME) {
  var node = document.querySelector(selector);
  node.classList.toggle(classNAME);
}

//~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

/* Method/Prop: cssText
|| CSS Property: background(-image); background(-repeat);
|| background-size: contain
*/
function scaleBkg(selector, url) {
  var node = document.querySelector(selector);
  node.style.cssText = `background: url(${url})no-repeat;background-size:contain`;
}
```

```css
figure {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  outline: 1px solid blue;
}

figcaption {
  position: absolute;
  top: -24px;
}

.scale {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
}

.oFit {
  object-fit: contain;
  min-width: 150px
}
```

```html
<figure id='fig1'>
  <figcaption><button onclick='wrap()'>Fig1</button></figcaption>
  <img src='https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2013/07/12/13/44/scales-147219_960_720.png' class='scale'>
</figure>


<figure id='fig2'>
  <figcaption>
    <button onclick="classSizer('#fig2 img', 'oFit')">Fig2</button>
  </figcaption>
  <img src='https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/236x/0d/fa/4d/0dfa4d2e1863e28ca9469c5cfdf4640f--lizards-for-sale-the-cuban.jpg' class='scale'>
</figure>


<figure id='fig3'>
  <figcaption>
    <button onclick="scaleBkg('#fig3', 'http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/0e/Music-Gclef.png')">Fig3</button>
  </figcaption>
</figure>
```

Answer (score 0):

Fill in the ? with a Javascript expression to set the scale for an image having a given original height and width so that it can exactly fit inside a maxdim-by-maxdim `square area` (touching at least two edges). *

In a square width === height so:

```
const scaleImage = (width, height, maxdim) => {

  const resized_width = (maxdim / width) * width;
  const resized_height = (maxdim / height) * height;

  return {
    resized_width,
    resized_height
  }
}

scaleImage(2, 5, 500);
```